# group rwx on directory but still permission denied

Tags: permissions, groups

I'm going insane. Not sure I'm having such an issue with something to basic. So, resorting here...

```
kevin@tobias:/srv/storage$ ll
total 40K
drwxrwxr-x 11 root storage 4.0K Sep 24 14:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root       0 Sep 24 14:42 ../
drwxrwxr-x  5 root storage 4.0K Jul 28 13:46 backup/
drwxrwxr-x 10 root storage 4.0K Sep 23 08:01 git/
drwxrwxr-x  9 root storage 4.0K Sep 24 08:26 misc/
drwxrwxr-x  7 root storage 4.0K Nov 27  2013 mythtv/
drwxrwxr-x  3 root storage 4.0K Sep 16 13:46 repos/

kevin@tobias:/srv/storage$ touch test
touch: cannot touch âtestâ: Permission denied

kevin@tobias:/srv/storage$ id
uid=1000(kevin) gid=1000(kevin) groups=1000(kevin),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),33(www-data),46(plugdev),109(sambashare),119(libvirtd),120(lpadmin),1002(storage)

kevin@tobias:/srv/storage$ groups
kevin adm cdrom sudo dip www-data plugdev sambashare libvirtd lpadmin storage
```

Any ideas what's happening?

My user (kevin) is in the group (storage) that has rwx perms to that dir.

I've tried logging out/back in and finally resorting to a reboot. Still the same issue.

If it's of any note this is an nfs mount via autofs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes "this is an nfs mount via autofs" is the key. Permissions on file/dirs mounted via NFS are controlled by how your UID maps into the NFS server's UID space (and what groups you have on the NFS server), and how the NFS volume is `mount`ed.

Do

```
mount | egrep '[[:blank:]]/srv'
```

to see how it's mounted.

Comment: That command has a syntax issue but the relevant output from the mount command is... 

storage:/storage on /mnt/nfs/storage type nfs (rw,addr=192.168.0.32)

Comment: Additionally, I have matched up the group and user id's on the client to the server. Still no change. This is a QNAP TS-431+ nas device, btw.